# How to end a file scanner while loop with undetermined length correctly in java

Tags: java

I wrote a function that scans a tab delimited file of baseball stats.

```
public static ArrayList dataRead() throws FileNotFoundException {
    //ArrayList array = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("c:\\stats.txt")).useDelimiter("\r");

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while(s.next() != null) {
        String currentLine = s.next();
        Scanner split = new Scanner(currentLine).useDelimiter("\t");
        for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            System.out.print(split.next() + " ");

            j++;

        }
        System.out.println("\r");
    }
    s.close();
    return array;
}
```

This function works until the end of the file. To my knowledge the while loop should close at the end of the file because it returns null, but I keep getting a noSuchElement error instead. If I could guarantee the file size, I would just use a for loop with the size, but I can't because team size could technically vary. How would I properly end the file scanner while loop so I can close the scanner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: [Javadocs for Scanner.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29)

> Throws:
>       NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

When there are no more lines left in the file, calling `s.next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` exception. You're also calling `s.next()` twice, once in the while() and once inside the loop. You should really be called `while(s.hasNext())` instead.

Comment: Got it moments after, not allowed to self answer yet. Thanks for the concern though :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `scanner.next()` use `scanner.hasNext()` in the loop condition to check, wether there is new element or not

Answer (score 0):

The for loop has two problems:

1. Why `j < 16`? If there are less than 16 tokens in a line then the would be an error. Pls consider using the while loop with `split.hasNext()` condition similarly as the outer while loop.
2. Index variable `j` is incremented twice -- once in the declaration of the for loop, and once again in be body of the same for loop.

The outer while loop needs to be corrected to use `hasNext()` instead of `next() != null`.

Comment: I got it. The length of each line is 17 tokens. The number of lines is variable. I noticed I forgot to use hasNext instead of next about two seconds after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
while(s.hasNext())
{
    //blah
}
```

Also use a `StringTokenizer` and not a `for loop` for tokens.

```
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(currentLine,"\t");
while(str.hasMoreTokens)
{
    System.out.print(str.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use s.hasNext()  in the while condition. If next token exists it will return true else false.

```
while(s.hasNext()){
}
```